# Samba connection GUI

Tags: samba, remote-access, file-server

I need to create a samba connection but I need my users to input their username and password by hand, so creating a connection using fstab is not possible.

I know you can do this by going to -> Other Locations -> Connect to server and then input the server address which prompts a new window where you can input username and password, but I can expect them to input the server address (or even remember where to find it) so I was wondering how to trigger that window from the terminal if possible.

If anybody has some other solution I'm all ears, just know that users have no access to root.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running (and whether it's Desktop or Server). This will help in troubleshooting your issue. Thanks